# Can you change the theme of an existing asp.net website?

Tags: css, asp.net, visual-studio, themes

Can you change the theme of an already created website in asp.net website from visual studio ?

Comment: In short, yes you can.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: I guess you can achieve that using CSS. Though you have to modify a lot of code now. If css was written in Saas then it would have been a minute job to change the theme.